# Parallel calls of sleep don't add up

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization

Using the subprocess module, I'm running 1000 calls to sleep(1) in parallel:

```
import subprocess
import time
start = time.clock()

procs = []
for _ in range(1000):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["sleep.exe", "1"])
    procs.append(proc)

for proc in procs:
    proc.communicate()

end = time.clock()
print("Executed in %.2f seconds" % (end - start))
```

On my 4-core machine, this results in an execution time of a couple of seconds, far less than I expected (~ 1000s / 4).

How does it get optimized away? Does it depend on the sleep implementation (this one is taken from the Windows-Git-executables)?

Comment: Well, of course the execution times of things happening in parallel don't add up. If I sleep for 8 hours at the same time you sleep for 8 hours, do 16 hours pass?

Comment: Why did you expect 500 seconds?

Comment: how did you come up with the 500 figure?

Comment: ehm, 250. I started with n=2000 but changed it to a "nicer" number ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sleeping doesn't require any processor time, so your OS can run far more than 4 sleep requests at a time, even though it has only 4 cores. Ideally it would be able to process the entire batch of 1000 in only 1 second, but there's lots of overhead in the creation and teardown of the individual processes.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, `subprocess.Popen(..)` is **not a blocking call**. The thread just triggers the child process creation and moves on. It does not wait for it to finish.

In other words, you are spawning 1000 asynchronous processes in a loop, and then waiting on them one by one later on. This asynchronous behavior results in your overall run time of a few seconds.

---

Calling `proc.communicate()` waits until the child process is complete (has exited). Now, if you want the sleep times to add up (minus the process creation/destruction) overhead, you'd do:

```
import subprocess
import time
start = time.clock()

procs = []

#Get the start time
for _ in range(10):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["sleep.exe", "1"])
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.communicate()

#Get the end time
```

---

> Does it depend on the sleep implementation (this one is taken from the Windows-Git-executables)?

As I've outlined above, this has nothing to do with implementation of sleep.